# How to extract elements from a list using indices in Python?

Tags: python, list

If you have a list in python, and want to extract elements at indices 1, 2 and 5 into a new list, how would you do this?

This is how I did it, but I'm not very satisfied:

```
>>> a
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> [x[1] for x in enumerate(a) if x[0] in [1,2,5]]
[11, 12, 15]
```

Is there a better way?

More in general, given a tuple of indices, how would you use this tuple to extract the corresponding elements from a list, even with duplication (e.g. tuple `(1,1,2,1,5)` produces `[11,11,12,11,15]`).

Comment: Is there a garantee that the tuple only contains valid indexes?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Perhaps use this:

```
[a[i] for i in (1,2,5)]
# [11, 12, 15]
```

Comment: btw this is also much faster. fetching K items from a list of size N is of complexity O(K) here and O(N*K) in OP's solution.

Comment: ok... thank you. This was damn trivial, and it's clear that I'm too tired.

Comment: No problem. Any day I can answer a Stefano Borini question is a (rare, but) good day :)

Comment: Personally I've never seen Python written that way, but I have to agree. That is pretty genius, and readable!

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for this:

```
elements = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
indices = (1,1,2,1,5)

result_list = [elements[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
numbers = range(10, 16)
indices = (1, 1, 2, 1, 5)

result = [numbers[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Numpy direct array indexing, as in MATLAB, Julia, ...

```
a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
s = [1, 2, 5] ;

import numpy as np
list(np.array(a)[s])
# [11, 12, 15]
```

Better yet, just stay with Numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
a[s]
#array([11, 12, 15])
```

Answer (score 3):

Bounds checked:

```
 [a[index] for index in (1,2,5,20) if 0 <= index < len(a)]
 # [11, 12, 15]
```